# Winnowative HTML to PDf - Display images from database

Tags: html, pdf, winnovative

All,

I am developing web application in which I have used Winnowative HTML to PDF component. 
I want to display images as well some text documents,PDF etc. in generated PDF. All the images,documents are saved in SQL Server database.

Along with HTML content how to display text,images etc. in generated PDF file saved in database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have 2 solutions. The first is based on saving the HTML in a folder on disk and the second is done in entirely in internal memory.

1. Construct a HTML file in a folder and save the referenced images in the same folder and convert that file to PDF. Make sure you use full URLs for image files like file:///C:/HTML/Images/image.jpg
2. Embed the images in HTML code like this [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) and then convert the HTML string to PDF.